# Loop to execute many files in R

Tags: r, loops, benchmarking

I apologize for asking this as I am really new to R. I have many data with similar names, e.g. **data_40231_2019**, **data_40232_2019**, and so on. I want to run these data to find Efficiency by using (Benchmark) with a loop. The variable name that I use for input is **real_40231_2019** and the output is **vol_40231_2019**. As you can see, the variable name follows the data name. Is there a way to loop this script?

Below is my current script; one-by-one. Also, I want to save it to a similar name.

```
  setwd   ("path")
  data    <- read.csv(file="data_40231_2019.csv", header=T, sep=",")
  data
  
  # input
  x1=data$real_40231_2019
  x=matrix(c(x1),length(x1),1);
  x
  
  # output
  y1=data$vol_40231_2019
  y=matrix(c(y1),length(y1),1);
  y
  
  # DEA
  efficiencies <- dea(x,y,RTS="vrs", ORIENTATION="in")
  efficiencies
  dea.plot.frontier(x,y,RTS="vrs")
  
  # summary
  efficiencies(efficiencies)
  print(efficiencies)
  summary(efficiencies)
  efficiencies
  
  # table
  DMU=data$dmu
  efficiencies <-c(efficiencies(efficiencies))
  efficiency <-cbind(DMU, efficiencies)
  efficiency
  
  # save
  file = "path"
  write.csv (efficiency, file="Efisiensi_40231_2019.csv")
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to store/save all the output of `print(efficiencies)`, `summary(efficiencies)` somewhere? or just print it in R session?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (this_file in list.files(pattern = 'data.*\\.csv', full.names = F)){
  
  this_str <- gsub('data_(.*)\\.csv','\\1',this_file); # 40232_2019
  this_str_real <- paste0('real_',this_str) # real_40232_2019
  this_str_vol <- paste0('vol_',this_str) # vol_40232_2019
    
  data    <- read.csv(file=this_file, header=T, sep=",")
  
  # input
  x1=data[[this_str_real]]
  x=matrix(c(x1),length(x1),1);
  
  # output
  y1=data[[this_str_vol]]
  y=matrix(c(y1),length(y1),1);
  
  # DEA
  efficiencies <- dea(x,y,RTS="vrs", ORIENTATION="in")
  png(filename = paste0(this_str,'_eff_plot.png'))
  dea.plot.frontier(x,y,RTS="vrs")
  dev.off()
  
  
  # CHANGE THE NEXT TWO SECTIONS IF YOU WANT TO SAVE OUTPUT IN THE FILE
  # YOU CAN USE THE LAST LINE (write.csv()) AS EXAMPLE
  
  # summary
  efficiencies(efficiencies)
  print(efficiencies)
  summary(efficiencies)
  efficiencies
  
  # table
  DMU=data$dmu
  efficiencies <-c(efficiencies(efficiencies))
  efficiency <- cbind(DMU, efficiencies)
  efficiency
  
  # save
  file = "path"
  write.csv(efficiency, file=paste0('Efisiensi_', this_str,".csv")) 
}
```